# Issue with Using Published NPM Library: Empty Object Returned when Consuming the Library

Tags: npm, webpack, libraries, publish, configuration-files

I am currently using ToolJet to create a report template. I have successfully built the project and published it to deployment platforms like Netlify. However, when I attempted to build it for publishing as an npm library, the build process was successful and I was able to publish my library on npm. Additionally, I can consume the library in another project.

However, when I try to use the library, it returns an empty object. For example, if I use the following code:

```
`
import * as props from 'my-library-name';

function Demo() {
  console.log("props", props);
}
`
```

I receive an empty object.

I have attached my configuration files and screenshots for reference. I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const environment =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development";

const API_URL = {
  production:
    process.env.TOOLJET_SERVER_URL ||
    (process.env.SERVE_CLIENT !== "false" ? "__REPLACE_SUB_PATH__" : ""),
  development: `http://localhost:${process.env.TOOLJET_SERVER_PORT || 3000}`,
};

const ASSET_PATH = process.env.ASSET_PATH || "";

function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
  return str.replace(/[/]+$/, "");
}

module.exports = {
  mode: environment,
  optimization: {
    minimize: environment === "production",
    usedExports: true,
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        minify: TerserPlugin.esbuildMinify,
        terserOptions: {
          ...(environment === "production" && { drop: ["debugger"] }),
        },
        parallel: environment === "production",
      }),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendor",
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  target: "web",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      ".js",
      ".jsx",
      ".png",
      ".wasm",
      ".tar",
      ".data",
      ".svg",
      ".png",
      ".jpg",
      ".jpeg",
      ".gif",
      ".json",
    ],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
      "@ee": path.resolve(__dirname, "ee/"),
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/"),
    },
  },
  devtool: environment === "development" ? "inline-source-map" : false,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.wasm$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tar$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.data$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "@svgr/webpack",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        },
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            plugins: [
              [
                "import",
                {
                  libraryName: "lodash",
                  libraryDirectory: "",
                  camel2DashComponentName: false,
                },
                "lodash",
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.ejs",
      favicon: "./assets/images/favicon.svg",
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      algorithm: "gzip",
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /(en)$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.ASSET_PATH": JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH),
      "process.env.SERVE_CLIENT": JSON.stringify(process.env.SERVE_CLIENT),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: { index: ASSET_PATH },
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
      publicPath: "/assets/",
    },
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: ASSET_PATH,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },
  externals: {
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: `${stripTrailingSlash(API_URL[environment]) || ""}/api`,
      SERVER_IP: process.env.SERVER_IP,
      COMMENT_FEATURE_ENABLE: process.env.COMMENT_FEATURE_ENABLE ?? true,
      ENABLE_TOOLJET_DB: process.env.ENABLE_TOOLJET_DB ?? true,
      ENABLE_MULTIPLAYER_EDITING: true,
      TOOLJET_MARKETPLACE_URL:
        process.env.TOOLJET_MARKETPLACE_URL ||
        "https://tooljet-plugins-production.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
    }),
  },
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "samaelnpmreportcs",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "private": false,
  "main": "build/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^6.0.5",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^7.0.1",
    "@dnd-kit/utilities": "^3.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-all": "^5.12.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-inputs": "^5.13.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.2",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.1.1",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.12.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.12.0",
    "@tabler/icons": "^1.91.1",
    "@tooljet/plugins": "file:../plugins",
    "@uiw/react-codemirror": "^3.0.6",
    "@y-presence/react": "^2.0.0",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.7",
    "dompurify": "^2.2.7",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.4.1",
    "driver.js": "^0.9.8",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.1",
    "focus-trap-react": "^10.0.0",
    "fuse.js": "^6.4.6",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "humps": "^2.0.1",
    "i18next": "^21.8.14",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "immer": "^9.0.6",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "plotly.js-basic-dist-min": "^1.58.4",
    "psl": "^1.8.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.6",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.5",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.38.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.8",
    "react-checkbox-tree": "^1.7.3",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.4",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-datetime": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
    "react-easy-sort": "^1.5.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.1.1",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "^3.4.4",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.3",
    "react-image-annotation": "^0.9.10",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.16.1",
    "react-json-view": "^1.21.3",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0",
    "react-mentions": "^4.3.0",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.2.3",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-qr-reader": "^2.2.1",
    "react-rnd": "^10.3.0",
    "react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select-search": "^3.0.5",
    "react-selecto": "^1.17.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4",
    "react-table": "^7.6.3",
    "react-table-plugins": "^1.3.1",
    "react-to-pdf": "^0.0.14",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.18",
    "react-virtuoso": "^2.17.2",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^2.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "semver": "^5.7.1",
    "superstruct": "^0.15.4",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.2",
    "url-join": "^5.0.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "y-websocket": "^1.4.0",
    "yjs": "^13.5.28",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-console-source": "^2.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@y-presence/react": {
      "react": "16.14.0",
      "react-dom": "16.14.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --port 8082 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production && cp -a ./assets/. ./build/assets/",
    "lint": "eslint . '**/*.{js,jsx}'",
    "format": "eslint . --fix '**/*.{js,jsx}'",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [],
    "development": []
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svg.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react|mpx-error-boundary)/)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ]
  }
```

index.js

```
import PatientDetails from “./Editor/PatientDetails/PatientDetails";
export { PatientDetails };
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'console-source',
      {
        segments: 1, // NOT REQUIRED
        // 0 = full file path (Default)
        // 1 = file name ONLY
        // 2 = file name and last segment
        splitSegment: '/', // How to split the path - NOT REQUIRED
        // Default is / for Linux and OSX
        // Windows users can use "\\" here if needed
      },
    ],
    ['@babel/transform-runtime'],
  ],
};
```

Folder structure    
[Based Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iQlG.png)
[inside src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdutU.png)

I have explored several approaches, such as utilizing rollup, in an attempt to facilitate the construction process. However, none of these methods have proven successful thus far. My objective is to export multiple modules, components, functions from the project, publish them, and enable their consumption as an npm library.